# Показывать контент при наведении на объект после задержки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста. Есть такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function showProfileTooltip(e, id){
   var top = e.clientY + 20;
   var left = e.clientX - 10;

   $('.p-tooltip').css({
    'top':top,
    'left':left,

   }).show();
   $.ajax({
    url: 'friends/dynamic_frds.php?id='+id,
    beforeSend: function(){
     $('.p-tooltip').html('Loading..');
    },
    success: function(html){
     $('.p-tooltip').html(html);
    }
   });
  }

  function hideProfileTooltip(){
   $('.p-tooltip').hide();
  }

  $('.fr').mouseover(function(e){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   showProfileTooltip(e, id);
  });

  $('.p-tooltip').mouseleave(function(){
   hideProfileTooltip();
  });
 });
```

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на объект не сразу показывался контент, а например через секунду после наведения, то есть если пользователь навел курсор на блок и подождал секунду, то загружаем контент. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь timeout.

стандартный шаблон на такие действия, срабатываем не сразу, вызываем событие один раз.

```
var TO;
function showProfileTooltip(e, id){
    clearTimeout(TO);
    TO=setTimeout(function() {
        //тут то что было раньше в функции
    },1000); //секунда это много....
}

function hideProfileTooltip(){
    clearTimeout(TO);
    showProfileTooltip(e, id);
}
```

Comment: @eicto
Простите конечно, но я как говорится нуб в jquery, сможете пожалуйста подставить куда это надо? Если вам не сложно.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev всё так-же как у вас, просто оберните тело showProfileTooltip() в то что я показал, и добавьте строчку в hideProfileTooltip() а var объявите сразу в document.ready

Comment: я там забыл присваивание сделать :) поправил.

Comment: вообще само по себе криво сделано, не надо на id ориентироваться :) вообще. щас покажу как правильно.

Comment: @eicto Да покажите пожалуйста.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/YjLbw/

Comment: @eicto Большое вам спасибо, работает все, а подскажите пожалуйста еще, как можно сделать чтобы блок исчезал не только при наведении на сам блок, а еще например на body, пробовал вставить     $('.fr').mouseover(showProfileTooltip);
не работало.

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте так:

```
success: function(html){
    $('.p-tooltip').delay(1000).html(html);
}
```

UPD: функции нужно объявлять вне $(document).ready(), а не внутри

Comment: @mountpoint
Нет что то не помогает.
Вот если вы сидели на youtube там при наведении например на имя пользователя через какое-то время выходит тултип, вот мне так нужно же что бы при наведении через пару секунд только выходил этот тултип.

Comment: delay работает только для анимации. загрузка все равно будет происходить.

> UPD: функции нужно объявлять вне $(document).ready(), а не внутри

с чего бы ?

Comment: @eicto, потому что в $(document).ready() должны выполнятся действия после загрузки DOM. А функции желательно загрузить сразу

Comment: @mountpoint вы жестоко ошибаетесь, функции нужно держать вне global, я бы еще понял, если бы вы объект предложили собрать с методами... или плагин jQuery. а вообще вполне нормально объявлять локальные функции в document.ready()